# How can I drag my UIView only from a specific area of this UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

This is the UIView I would like to have. Most of it would be hidden and could be dragged out ONLY by dragging the little visible part.

[image]

I thought about drawing my view up to let say 90% of its container and on the top, draw a little rectangle (the visible part) but then I faced 2 problems:

- I can drag my view out by dragging any visible part of my view (and not just the little rectangle) and
- I need to be able to see/interact with the view behind the visible part of my hidden view (except for the little rectangle)

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override [`pointInside:withEvent:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/pointInside:withEvent:) to return false when the point is in the part of the view where you don't want to receive touches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use panGesture,in `shouldReceiveTouch` check the touch point.

For example

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
var panGestureRecognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "gestureRecognizer:");
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer!)
}
func catchedPan(gesture:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    switch gesture.state{
    case .Began:

    case .Changed:
        //Change frame here
    case .Ended:
    default:
    }
}
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if(gestureRecognizer == panGestureRecognizer){
        let point = touch.locationInView(self.view);
        if (point inside your area){
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Rob's answer is quicker for me to use. Thanks anyway